# Quickfix does not replay to my message

Tags: c, quickfix, fix-protocol

I have a simple exchange simulator that uses [Quickfix](http://www.quickfixengine.org/). In my test I have a client that establishes a connection with the exchange and send it a FIX message to log on. But for some reason the exchange doesn't acknowledge the message. My client then retransmits the message, but it is ignored again.

Any idea what I do wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon if you've not already done so.  Please do show us an MCVE ([How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).  Without that, all we can say is "you did it wrong" and "you need to change something", but we can't even begin to guess what you did wrong and how it needs to be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

How do you know your QF client establishes the connection with the exchange? Have you looked in your log directory for the response to the logon message?

What does your config file say?